# How to solve the url loading issue in the latest Firefox version-34?

Tags: selenium, automation

When I update my **firefox** browser to 34th version I found browser is not **loading the url**, when I automate the script using **Selenium-java**. when I downgrade to its lower version then it is loading well but I need to execute it in latest version(34th ver) only. Please give me the solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Update](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) your webdriver. webdriver 2.43.1 fixes the issue with firefox. 2.44 is the latest stable release if I am not mistaking